# I can't boot with external media because my keyboard does not work

Tags: boot, keyboard, bios

My keyboard (USB) functions well when the system starts (and I can enter BIOS by pressing <kbd>DEL</kbd> key), but when it comes to the boot from CD screen I can't press anything. Again, when it comes to OS selection menu I can't access the keyboard again. But when the computer starts, the keyboard functions well.

The biggest problem is that I can't install other operating system or even boot with a CD.

Comment: Is this a backlit keyboard, or does it otherwise have any other unusual features (integrated USB hub, a heads-up programmable display ala the Logitech G15, or anything like that?)  I've seen issues where certain motherboards don't supply sufficient power over USB for a device like that to start working quickly enough to be able to interact with some of these screens properly.

Comment: Have you checked your BIOS settings if the USB keyboard is activated completely? Some models have an "USB DOS" feature that needs to be enabled for "pressing the key".

Comment: Usually called USB Legacy Mode

Comment: ...or it could be that setting, yeah.  Felt like I was missing something obvious... :)

Comment: Oh Yeah! I haven't seen that setting before. My keyboard is working well now! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked your BIOS settings if the USB keyboard is activated completely?

Some models have an option called "USB DOS" or "USB legacy" that needs to be enabled for making the keyboard work at the moment you have to "pressing the key".